# How to create objects that reference the previous object in a list in R?

Tags: r, list, object, vector, dplyr

Is there any way to reference objects being created within a list in R? I know that outside of a list this is possible, but I can't do that within a list.

A reproducible example of what I would like to do:

```
my_list <- list(
  
  a = 1:3,
  b = c("a", "b", "c"),
  c = b        # Error: object 'b' not found
  
  )
```

The result I would like to have:

```
> structure(my_list)
$a
[1] 1 2 3

$b
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$c
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with `dplyr::lst` or `purrr::lst`

```
my_list <- dplyr::lst(
  a = 1:3,
  b = c("a", "b", "c"),
  c = b       
)
```

-output

```
my_list
#$a
#[1] 1 2 3

#$b
#[1] "a" "b" "c"

#$c
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**1a) within** In base R use within:

```
my_list <- within(list(a = 1:3, b = c("a", "b", "c")), { c = b })

str(my_list)
## List of 3
##  $ a: int [1:3] 1 2 3
##  $ b: chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
##  $ c: chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
```

**1b)** It could also be written like this:

```
my_list2 <- within(list(a = NA, b = NA, c = NA), {
  a = 1:3
  b = c("a", "b", "c")
  c = b
})
```

**1c)** or like this.  Omit the [...] at the end if the order of the components does not matter.

```
my_list3 <- within(list(), {
  a = 1:3
  b = c("a", "b", "c")
  c = b
})[c("a", "b", "c")]
```

**2) local** Another approach is to create an environment and then convert that to list.

```
as.list(local({
  a = 1:3
  b = c("a", "b", "c")
  c = b
  environment()
}))
```

**3) proto** Create a proto object and then convert that to list.

```
library(proto)

as.list(proto(expr = {
  a = 1:3
  b = c("a", "b", "c")
  c = b
}))
```